# Convert iterator over Result into Result<Vec<_>, _>

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a function that converts the output from [glob](https://docs.rs/glob/0.3.0/glob/fn.glob.html) which is `Result<Paths, PatternError>` into `Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Error>`. I have my own `Error` type that implements `From` for both `glob::GlobError` and `glob::PatternError`. Currently I have the following implemented:

```rust
fn glob_abs_path(fpath: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Error> {
    Ok(glob(fpath)?.map(|val| val.unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>())
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to remove the call to `val.unwrap` and allow for a `GlobError` to be returned if encountered. I tried using `collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>()?` but that did not work.

Apologies if the question title is cryptic. I am new to rust and don't have the familiarity yet to express this question concisely.

Comment: "I tried using `collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>()?` but that did not work" - because `Result` has two type parameters. `collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>` (note the second underscore) should do.

Comment: `collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?` produces a similar error to what I have been seeing thus far: `a value of type 'std::result::Result<Vec<_>, error::Error>' cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type 'std::result::Result<PathBuf, GlobError>'`

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=387b02556ea47d63ab2ed5e3ae2e5629), perhaps I missed something?

Comment: @kmdreko something fishy going on. You are right, there is no error in your snippet. The only difference between that and mine is that I have `type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>` defined and the function return is thus `Result<Vec<PathBuf>>`. When I use my own `Result` definition I still get an error - [see here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b4aba7ca465df706c5650bbdbafcca78)

Comment: You're collecting into `Result<Vec<_>, Error>`, but it is possible only if iterator items are `Result<_, Error>`. When you collect into `Result<Vec<_>, _>` and convert the error after collecting, it works - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63eeb7b504e35dc5f542b41474545636.

Comment: @Cerberus hmm I'm a bit at a loss here, mind elaborating? I see in your solution that instead of `type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>` you have `type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>`. I tried the latter and now it works for me too. What am I missing and why wouldn't `collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>()?` work?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here:

```rust
fn glob_abs_path(fpath: &str) -> std::result::Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Error> {
  Ok(glob(fpath)?.map(|val| val.unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>())
}
```

At the end of `glob_abs_path`, you are collecting the value into a `Vec`. If you try to use the `?` operator on a vec, it will fail:

```rust
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be applied to values that implement `std::ops::Try`
  --> src/lib.rs:26:8
   |
26 |     Ok(glob(fpath)?.map(|val| val.unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()?)
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the `?` operator cannot be applied 
to type `std::vec::Vec<std::result::Result<std::path::PathBuf, glob::GlobError>>`
```

The `?` operator can only be applied to values that implement `std::ops::Try`, namely `Result<_, _>`. So what we have to do is collect the iterator into a `Result`:

```rust
fn glob_abs_path(fpath: &str) -> std::result::Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Error> {
  Ok(glob(fpath)?.map(|val| val.unwrap()).collect::<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?)
}
```

However, we get another error here:

```rust
error[E0277]: a value of type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<_>, _>` cannot be built 
from an iterator over elements of type `std::path::PathBuf`
  --> src/lib.rs:26:43
   |
26 |   Ok(glob(fpath)?.map(|val| val.unwrap()).collect::<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, _>>())
   |                                           ^^^^^^^ value of type 
   |  `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<_>, _>` cannot be built from 
   |  `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::path::PathBuf>`
   |
```

The issue here is that we are unwrapping the value `.map(|val| val.unwrap())` before collecting it, and the iterator does not know how to convert the unwrapped value (`PathBuf` ) to a `Result`. Removing the call to unwrap fixes the issue:

```rust
fn glob_abs_path(fpath: &str) -> std::result::Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Error> {
    Ok(glob(fpath)?.collect::<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?)
}
```

The code now compiles. You mentioned that you had a type alias for `Result`:

```rust
type MyResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>
```

You can use this type alias in the return value:

```rust
fn glob_abs_path(fpath: &str) -> MyResult<Vec<PathBuf>> {
    Ok(glob(fpath)?.collect::<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?)
}
```

However, when you use it in to collect the iterator:

```rust
fn glob_abs_path(fpath: &str) -> MyResult<Vec<PathBuf>> {
    Ok(glob(fpath)?.collect::<MyResult<Vec<_>>>()?)
}
```

It fails:

```rust
error[E0277]: a value of type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<_>, Error>` 
cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::result::Result<std::path::PathBuf, glob::GlobError>`
  --> src/lib.rs:26:21
   |
26 |     Ok(glob(fpath)?.collect::<MyResult<Vec<_>>>()?)
   |                     ^^^^^^^ value of type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<_>, Error>` 
   |  cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::result::Result<std::path::PathBuf, glob::GlobError>>`
   |
```

This is because `MyResult` explicitly states the return value as your custom Error type. `Iterator` cannot convert `GlobError` to your `Error`. That conversion is handled by the `?` operator:

```rust
fn glob_abs_path(fpath: &str) -> MyResult<Vec<PathBuf>> {
  Ok(glob(fpath)?.collect::<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, GlobError>>()?)
}
```

As you can see above, the iterator is collected into `<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, GlobError>`, and then converted into `std::result::Result<Vec<_>, YourError>` (`MyResult`) by the `?` operator.

Here is the final working code as a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19b89ec137654f11a58010772bd350c7)